# Creating hard drive backup images efficiently

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, cleaning

We are in the process of pruning our directories to recuperate some disk space.

The 'algorithm' for the pruning/backup process consists of a list of directories and, for each one of them, a set of rules, e.g. 'compress *.bin', 'move *.blah', 'delete *.crap', 'leave *.important'; these rules change from directory to directory but are well known. The compressed and moved files are stored in a temporary file system, burned onto a blue ray, tested within the blue ray, and, finally, deleted from their original locations.

I am doing this in Python (basically a `walk` statement with a dictionary with the rules for each extension in each folder).

Do you recommend a better methodology for pruning file systems? How do you do it?

We run on Linux.

Comment: If the data is deleted from its original location, the BluRay isn't really a backup.

Answer (score 1):

I had a system for dropping aged backups from an partition of backup tarballs. Each host had it's own directory. Within each directory I would define a file (e.g. `00info`) that my pruner would read and run a find against. The problem it encountered was when the backups entering the directory didn't match the patterns in the file. It used bin/find primarily, like

```
foreach pat in $patterns; do find . -type f -name "$pat" -mtime +7 | xargs rm -f ; done
```

This was not great, but it was very simple. And I find that if it's simple to maintain, you'll have time to actually maintain it among normal everyday pressures.

If you're programming in python, a bash script isn't going to compare to what you're capable of. So the important thing I'd suggest is: don't feel guilty for having something no-one else uses: you've created a solution that is correct for *your* requirements, and you can't be more correct than that.

Is there an actual problem your script isn't solving, though? Has it become difficult to maintain the rule-set?

Answer (score 0):

I like the sound of what you are doing.

There is a program called [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)  that does something similar.   Maybe it can be extended?

[image]

Also, another tool called  [Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) might give you some ideas.